# Using std::copy on random access memory iterators

Tags: c++, iterator, copy

I am in the middle of a migration process from VS2008 to VS2013 and I receive an error on the following line which used to compile fine in VS2008:

```
std::copy(inIterator, inIterator + size , stdext::checked_array_iterator<T::ImgIterator>(outIterator, size)) ;
```

in inIterator, outIterator and ImgIterator are all defined as `random_access_iterator_tag` type iterators.

The error which I receive is:

```
error C2665: 'std::_Copy_impl' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types
```

I believe the problem is with the iterator types but I am not sure exactly what is the problem or how to fix it (without changing the iterator debug level).

EDIT2: const_ImgIterator is defined as follows:

```
class ImgIterator : public _Ranit<T,difference_type,pointer,reference> {
```

and _Ranit is defined in xutility:

```
template<class _Ty,
class _Diff,
class _Pointer,
class _Reference>
struct _Ranit
    : public _Iterator_with_base<random_access_iterator_tag,
        _Ty, _Diff, _Pointer, _Reference>
{   // base type for container random-access iterator classes
};
```

EDIT: added the build output:

```
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xutility(2107): error C2665: 'std::_Copy_impl' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types
          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xutility(2092): could be '_OutIt std::_Copy_impl<_InIt,_OutIt>(_InIt,_InIt,_OutIt,std::random_access_iterator_tag,std::random_access_iterator_tag)'
          with
          [
              _OutIt=stdext::checked_array_iterator<CImg<unsigned char,std::allocator<unsigned char>>::ImgIterator>
  ,            _InIt=CImg<unsigned char,std::allocator<unsigned char>>::const_ImgIterator
          ]
          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xutility(2083): or       '_OutIt std::_Copy_impl<_InIt,_OutIt>(_InIt,_InIt,_OutIt,std::input_iterator_tag,std::_Mutable_iterator_tag)'
          with
          [
              _OutIt=stdext::checked_array_iterator<CImg<unsigned char,std::allocator<unsigned char>>::ImgIterator>
  ,            _InIt=CImg<unsigned char,std::allocator<unsigned char>>::const_ImgIterator
          ]
          while trying to match the argument list '(CImg<unsigned char,std::allocator<T>>::const_ImgIterator, CImg<unsigned char,std::allocator<T>>::const_ImgIterator, stdext::checked_array_iterator<CImg<unsigned char,std::allocator<T>>::ImgIterator>, std::input_iterator_tag, std::input_iterator_tag)'
          with
          [
              T=unsigned char
          ]
          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xutility(2132) : see reference to function template instantiation '_OutIt std::_Copy_impl<_Iter,_OutIt>(_InIt,_InIt,_OutIt,std::true_type)' being compiled
          with
          [
              _OutIt=stdext::checked_array_iterator<CImg<unsigned char,std::allocator<unsigned char>>::ImgIterator>
  ,            _Iter=CImg<unsigned char,std::allocator<unsigned char>>::const_ImgIterator
  ,            _InIt=CImg<unsigned char,std::allocator<unsigned char>>::const_ImgIterator
          ]
          q:\airi\images\img_alg.h(298) : see reference to function template instantiation '_OutIt std::copy<CImg<unsigned char,std::allocator<T>>::const_ImgIterator,stdext::checked_array_iterator<CImg<T,std::allocator<T>>::ImgIterator>>(_InIt,_InIt,_OutIt)' being compiled
          with
          [
              _OutIt=stdext::checked_array_iterator<CImg<unsigned char,std::allocator<unsigned char>>::ImgIterator>
  ,            T=unsigned char
  ,            _InIt=CImg<unsigned char,std::allocator<unsigned char>>::const_ImgIterator
          ]
          q:\airi\images_mil_part\img_alg_mil.cpp(182) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void ImgAlg::Window<CImgAlgMil::CByteImg>(const T &,T &,const CPixelWindow &)' being compiled
          with
          [
              T=CImgAlgMil::CByteImg
          ]
```

Comment: Read the details in the  'Build Output'

Comment: I did but I do not fully understand the problem from it.
Added it to the question.

Comment: `CImg<..>::const_ImgIterator` seems not to be set up properly. The argument list in the build output suggests MSVC thinks it's an input iterator, instead of a RA iterator. Please add some info/code on how you've set the iterator category of this type.

Comment: @dyp added the code for const_ImgIterator.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to VS2013, and my attempts to find `_Ranit` with online compilers have failed so far. Including `<xutility>` works, but `_Ranit` is not found (neither in the global namespace nor in namespace `std`). -- Anyway, if `ImgIterator` is your own class, you shouldn't inherit from the nonstandard `_Ranit`. There's no required inheritance hierarchy for iterators, only a hierarchy of *concepts*. There is [`std::iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator), which sets up some types and the iterator category. Please try to use that instead of `_Ranit`.